# Opening txt files in Internet Explorer 8 parses some html

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm not sure if it's just me, but whenever I open .txt files in internet explorer, it always parses the HTML, so forms, buttons, fields all show up. It does this on multiple computers, and I'm fairly sure it hasn't always done this. I know FireFox doesn't, FireFox loads it as a text file. Does anyone else have this problem? If so, have you solved it? If so again, how?

Comment: Not a programming problem. It's a software problem. Belongs on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is probably somewhere the content-type is incorrect, it should be text/plain, make sure its not text/html.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. I always assumed .txt files would assume the text/plain content type.

Comment: "content="text/html;" You called it. Thanks.